# Parametrize an helicoid around a spiral

Tags: geometry, surfaces, algebraic-curves

I need to find the parametric equation of an helicoid wrapped around a spiral.
Just like the example.

[Helicoid around a spiral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxFpt.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have better and arrange to work with a double polar system,
 - one ($R,\alpha$) on the $x-y$ plane describing the spiral,
 - and one($r,\phi$) on the $n-z$ plane describing the helicoid
where $n$ is the (unit vector) normal to the spiral.

Both the spiral and the helicoid are supposedly linear.

Let's put
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  \alpha  = 2\,\pi \,t \hfill \cr 
  \varphi  = 2\,\pi \,m\,t \hfill \cr 
  {\bf k} = \left( {0,0,1} \right) \hfill \cr 
  {\bf p}(t) = \left( {x(t),\;y(t),\;z(t)} \right) \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$
where the meaning of the various parameters is clear.

Then we shall have
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  {\bf R}(t) = \left( {R_{\,0}  + c\,t} \right)\left( {\cos \alpha ,\;\sin \alpha ,\;0} \right) \hfill \cr 
  {d \over {dt}}{\bf R}(t) = 2\,\pi \left( {R_{\,0}  + c\,t} \right)\left( { - \sin \alpha ,\;\cos \alpha ,0} \right) + c\left( {\cos \alpha ,\;\sin \alpha ,\;0} \right) \hfill \cr 
  {\bf N}(t) = {d \over {dt}}{\bf R}(t) \times {\bf k} = \left( {2\,\pi \left( {R_{\,0}  + c\,t} \right)\cos \alpha  + c\sin \alpha ,\;2\,\pi \left( {R_{\,0}  + c\,t} \right)\sin \alpha  - c\cos \alpha ,0} \right) \hfill \cr 
  {\bf n}(t) = {\bf N}(t)/\left| {{\bf N}(t)} \right| \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

And finally
$$
{\bf p}(t) = {\bf R}(t) + r\cos \varphi (t)\;{\bf n}(t) + r\sin \varphi (t)\;{\bf k}
$$